# PHP - HTML characters posted within Tweet status

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

When using Abrahams/TwitterOAuth library, special HTML characters are placed in a Tweet.

```
$content = "test's";

$params = array(
"status" => $content
);

$result = $connection->post("statuses/update", $params);
```

results in

```
test&#039;s
```

within the posted Tweet status.

A `vardump($content)` in the browser reveals `test's` as expected.

I've tried `html_entity_decode` and `htmlspecialchars_decode` but neither work for the posted Tweet.

Comment: Refer this http://www.designwall.com/question/symbols-in-twitter-shared-urls-instead-of-single-quotes/

Comment: Questions/issues with answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  $content = "test's";
  $content = htmlspecialchars_decode($content, ENT_QUOTES);
```

works for me.

Thanks chris85!

Comment: Your response was initially a comment, hence the answer.

Comment: It was a comment, then an answer. It was made an answer over 19 hours ago. See `answered yesterday`..

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it explicitly to convert the quotes. This is done with `ENT_QUOTES`.

Example:

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode('test&#039;s',ENT_QUOTES) . "\n";
echo htmlspecialchars_decode('test&#039;s');
```

Output:

```
test's
test&#039;s
```

Demo: https://eval.in/426992

There are also other constants that can be used if you only want to decode single quotes etc. See the manual for more information, http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php.

> **ENT_QUOTES** Will convert both double and single quotes.